# Gaussian Distribution Under Orthogonal Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-matrices, invariance

Let $\mathbf{H}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a random matrix whose every element has a Gaussian distribution with mean $m_{ij}$ and variance $\sigma^2$ i.e. $h_{ij}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(m_{ij},\sigma^2\right)$, where $h_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)^{th}$ element of $\mathbf{H}$. Let us denote the probability density function(pdf) of $\mathbf{H}$ as $p_{\mathbf{H}}$. Now define a random matrix as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{HU}
\end{equation}
where, $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, n > m$ is an orthogonal matrix. How does the pdf of $\mathbf{Y}$, denoted as $p_{\mathbf{Y}}$, relate to $p_{\mathbf{H}}$. I know that $p_{\mathbf{Y}} =p_{\mathbf{H}}$ when $m=n$ as per theorem 2.1.6, page 58, Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory, Robb J. Muirhead. But can we say the same when $n>m$?

Comment: You haven't told us what the JOINT distribution if $h_{ij}$ is. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I forgot to mention two things. Each element is distributed independent of others and $\mathbf{H}$ is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: In standard usage, "orthogonal matrix" means a square matrix whose inverse is its transpose.  Your matrix $\mathbf U$ is not square. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You can assume that $\mathbf{U}$ belongs to the Stiefel Manifold, $V_{m,n}$ such that $V_{m,n} = \{\mathbf{U}:\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{I}_m\}$. I used abuse of terminology to mention $\mathbf{U}$ as orthogonal.

Comment: The domain of the latter density is of course a space of lower dimension.

Comment: Very well pointed out. But how do we get this density?

Comment: Probably I'll look at this tomorrow or Saturday.  It looks similar to some exercises in a course I took a long time ago.  I'm rusty on that stuff. ${}\qquad{}$